# TypeScript override for ES6 Promise with Bluebird

Tags: typescript, bluebird

I have a Node.js library that uses promises, with its TypeScript declarations using ES6 `Promise`, even though the library itself can be customized to use any promise library.

So, I have no problem passing in `Bluebird` into that library so it can use it.

The problem is how to make Bluebird promise interface visible on declarative level, since my library declares its interface only through ES6 `Promise`.

Is there a way to make the compiler aware that I am using a different Promise protocol, without having to modify the library itself?

The latter, of course, is the catch, as there would be no question if I could just modify the library.

And if it is of any help to understand what that library is like, let's take this simple interface from it:

```
interface Protocol {
    methodName(param1:string, param2:number):Promise<Object[]>
}
```

and then multiply its size 1000 times.

So, I can't just fake the protocol with my own file. I need to figure out how to tell the compiler that `Promise` isn't the default ES6, but the one that Bluebird TypeScript provides.

Comment: You can include your own definition file that overrides the library's definitions. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I can't override the entire library with my own file, the library's interface is huge.

Comment: Well, you *can*, you just don't want to ;). The only other way I can think of would be to `import Promise = bluebird.Promise` (or [whatever the syntax is](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Namespaces%20and%20Modules.md)) at the top of all of the library's definition files.

Comment: Is it something that can be injected, somehow, without modifying the original library files?

Comment: I can't think of any way of doing it, but maybe others have better ideas...

Comment: Would casting to a bluebird promise in your code or using the bluebird promise constructor on the returned object be out of the question?

Comment: I'm tempted to close it in favor of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36593087/using-a-custom-promise-as-a-generic-type

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly overwrite the Promise type using a union https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types

**This is the non-preferred way**

```
import Bluebird from 'bluebird';

type Promise = Promise | Bluebird;
```

---

Taking from [@Paarth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2557260/paarth)'s comment above, you could typecast your Bluebird promise to a ES6 Promise.

**This is the preferred way**

Given the 3rd party library as:

```
interface Protocol {
    methodName(param1:string, param2:number):Promise<Object[]>
}
```

You could consume it like so:

```
import Bluebird from 'bluebird';

class Http implements Protocol {
  methodName(url: string, payload: number): Promise<Object[]> {
    return <Promise<Object[]>>new Bluebird((resolve, reject) => {

      // Do whatever you need to do ... use the url & payload

      resolve([{ data: 'Done' }]);
    });
  }
}


let http = new Http();

http.methodName('//get-some-data', 10);
```

*disclaimer: I haven't compiled this to test it - I don't have an environment set up at the moment and jsbin is playing havoc with the Typescript compiler*