# Using a custom promise as a generic type

Tags: typescript, promise, bluebird

I have an ambient TypeScript module represent a library that supports any Promises/A+ library:

```
interface Test {
  funcName():Promise<string>;
}
```

So I need to adjust it in such a way as to make the protocol of any promise library accessible on declarative level:

```
interface Test<P> {
  funcName():P<string>;
}
```

But the TypeScript immediately complains: `Type 'P' is not generic`, before I even use it.

Note that I cannot include a custom promise library into the same file as `Test`, because I have to pass it in from another module.

And if I change the code to this:

```
interface AnyPromise<T, P extends Promise<T>> {
}

interface Test<P> {
    funcName():AnyPromise<string, P<string>>;
}
```

It also complains `error TS2315: Type 'P' is not generic.` within this part: `P<string>`.

In the end I need to be able to do something like this:

```
import * as promise from 'bluebird'; // from Bluebird ambient declarations 
import {Test} from 'test';

var Test<promise> t; // plus initialize it;

t.funcName().finally(())=>{
}); // NOTE: 'finally' is to be visible from Bluebird (doesn't exist in ES6 Promise)
```

To clarify again, I use Bluebird just as an example, as I need a solution to support any promise library, not one specific.

Comment: Why `Test<typeof promise>`, shouldn't it just be `Test<promise>`?

Comment: @Bergi that tells the compiler to treat the variable as a class. But it doesn't matter, because the error occurs before that call, while parsing class `Test`. I have updated the question ;)

Comment: You need to define a `then`able structural interface, although I think bluebird would structurally pass as an ES2015 promise since it has exactly the same function signatures.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Bluebird has a lot of extra methods on top of the standard Promise protocol that I want to have access to, so I'm trying to figure out how it can be templated in as a dynamic parameter.

Comment: Oh, you want the type of the returned promise to depend on the type of the input promise? I don't think TS does that but I'll ping @spion who is literally the only other person on earth that is deeply interested in this :P (update: after some thought it doesn't sound too hard to model this with generics in general and I see how I could easily do it in C++)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum that's exactly what I want. I've had lots productive talks with spion in the past, I hope he can help with this one too :) I have been asked to do this by other developers, and I came to a point when I'm not sure myself if this is possible. Some TS generics guru suggest it is, but I'm yet to see it work...

Comment: as I understand you ain't gonna use the standard Promise, are you? Why can't you then just extend a Promise with the Bluebird's signature?

Comment: @smnbbrv I don't need to extend `Promise` with one specific promise library, I need generic custom promise support, that's the problem. As stated at the very top, it is for an ambient module that represents a library which supports any custom promise library.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely. Generic type parameter `P` is supposed to be a Promise itself, or act as the *type parameter* of a Promise?

Comment: It looks like you want higher-kinded generics, which typescript does not support.

Comment: @JohnWhite `P` is the custom promise that we are trying to use, something that implements the basic `Promise` protocol, plus a lot more.

Comment: @Lee My reads of all the information around similar problems point out at a possibility that a certain combination of extensible generics with concatenated types (T1&T2) could produce the desired result. I just haven't been able to put it all together. Who knows, you may be right, and it's simply impossible, but I'd like a conclusive verdict on this.

Comment: The interface name `Test` doesn't tell much. So if I get it right, you are deliberately looking for a signature that accepts a *generic type* as the *generic type parameter*, aren't you? Because if so, it's not possible in TS AFAIK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This requires higher kinded types to land in TypeScript. The issue that tracks them is here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213

As of April 2016, its not yet possible.

You can approximate some of it with product types, but it needs a modification of the `PromiseLike` type and you will need to explicitly pass the type parameter around any time you use `then` within your library:

```
interface HKPromiseLike<T> {
    then<TResult, P>(onfulfilled?: (value: T) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>, onrejected?: (reason: any) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>): P & HKPromiseLike<TResult>;
    then<TResult, P>(onfulfilled?: (value: T) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>, onrejected?: (reason: any) => void): P & HKPromiseLike<TResult>;
}

class Wrapper<T, P> {
    constructor(public p:P & HKPromiseLike<T>) {}

    map<U>(f:(t:T) => U) {
        var res = this.p.then<U, P>(f)
        var w = new Wrapper(res);
        return w
    }
}
```

To specialize this wrapper, you must use class/extends.

```
class Specialized<T> extends Wrapper<T, SomePromise<T>> { }
```

Comment: Going through that TypeScript feature progress, prospects to ever see it are rather dim.

Comment: I've been asked to implement this feature, but I failed time and again. Just hesitated to say NO, it's impossible, due to my lack of TypeScript knowledge. Now I feel confident to say that it is in fact impossible, and that the way I'm doing it in my library is the only (though ugly) way to do it - manually patching with the custom promise: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/blob/master/typescript/promise.ts. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: I recommend commenting on the TypeScript issue and  adding your problem there. It will show the TS team that the features is useful and not just for FP style code...

Comment: I commented on that within the library: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/blob/master/typescript/ext-promise.ts#L21, but do you mean on the TypeScript list of issues?

Comment: Would you, please, update your answer and add how it can be done with TypeScript 2.0 now that it is out? Cheers!

Comment: Never mind, please see an updated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40993251/generic-promise-with-typescript-2-0

Comment: It can't be done with TypeScript 2.0 either. If you check the issue, you can see its still open.

Comment: Bummer, I'll go break something.... 1 year of waiting for TypeScript 2.0, and all for naught.

Comment: With the release of TypeScript 2.4, and this new feature: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#return-types-as-inference-targets, do you think it may now be finally possible? And if so, then please update your answer, it would be very valuable! Thank you!

Comment: The higher-kinded generics issue is still open, so I don't believe it is.